# Como exibir um modal utilizando o compoente button do c# e bootstrap?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-3, modal

Se utilizar o `<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ConvenioOk">Teste </button>` o modal abre. Mas tenho que usar o botão do C# devido ao evento. O botão chamando o modal está assim`<asp:Button  ID="btnCadastrarCon"  runat="server" data-togggle="modal" data-target="#ConvenioOk" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="btnCadastrarCon_Click" />`

Existe alguma forma de usar modal com o botão do asp, mesmo sem utilizar o bootstrap? Se sim, podem dar exemplos?

Comment: Você pode escrever seu java script para abrir modal no backend.
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode exibir seu `modal` a partir do `backend` usando o `ScriptManager`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { funcaoQueExibeModal(); });", true);
```

No seu aspx:

```
function funcaoQueExibeModal() {
            $('#minhaModal').modal();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

certamente, no entanto você terá que construir seu próprio modal. Isto é, interceptar o clique no browser, criar o JavaScript / CSS para exibir o modal. Na minha opinião dá mais trabalho, mas segue um exemplo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603898/1384539